# Python Decimal module not rounding as expected

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

I am trying to use the Decimal module to do some FX calculations (instead of using floats).

However when I do the following, I do not get the expected value output:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> x = Decimal(1.3755)
>>> y = Decimal(1.2627)
>>> z = y/(1/x)
>>> print(z)
1.736843849999999839084452447
>>>
```

The output should be: 1.73684385

I thought using Decimals would correct this issue. How can I resolve this rounding issue?

Comment: use round , `round(z, 5)`

Comment: I don't want to have to round, I just want to get the full output 1.73684385 without having to guess what to round to, in this case I'd need round(z, 8)

Comment: set the getcontext().prec  which will gives what you excected

Answer (score 4):

```py
from decimal import Decimal
x = Decimal('1.3755')
y = Decimal('1.2627')
print(y/(1/x))
# 1.736843850000000000000000000
```

Use `str` to construct `Decimal` instead of real number.

Comment: Note that there's still a certain amount of luck involved here - you need the roundings to go the right way. With these particular values this "works", but if you try with `x = Decimal('5.73')` and `y = Decimal('6.7')`, then `print(y/(1/x))` gives `38.39099999999999999999999999` rather than the expected `38.39100000000000000000000000`.

Answer (score 2):

String decimal objects are required:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> x = Decimal('1.3755')
>>> y = Decimal('1.2627')
>>> z = y/(1/x)
>>> print(z)
1.736843850000000000000000000
>>>
```

Otherwise they would still be treated as regular python floats.

As @schwobaseggl mentioned:

> Note that the float is passed to the Decimal constructor, so the precision is lost there already. The Decimal constructor has no chance of knowing the desired precision. The result is still a decimal object, but with the precision of the passed float.

Comment: Note that the float is passed to the Decimal constructor, so the precision is lost there already. The Decimal  constructor has no chance of knowing the desired precision. The result is still a decimal object, but with the precision of the passed float.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yeap, I will edit that in! thanks man

Answer (score 1):

you can use `0:.nf` to round the numbers like below
:

```
print(z)
# 1.736843849999999839084452447
print("{0:.8f}".format(z))
# 1.73684385
```

Comment: This does not explain at all why the issue occurs with `Decimal` objects who when handled with intent deal with the precision themselves. This question is not about string formatting.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but how do you know how many relevant the digit the result has?

Answer (score 0):

try this, this will helps you, set your precision level

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 6
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.142857')
>>> getcontext().prec = 28
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
```